# Adding an image in Latex - but image not in right place

Tags: floats

I've put in an image in my Overleaf latex file but it's positioned in the wrong place. How can I move it around?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{logo}
\end{figure}
```

`h` indicates that the float is allowed to be placed inline. Instead of h, you can use t for top and b for bottom. There is more on floating environment. But you seems beginner so.

Comment: Use only `[h]` for image placement can cause problems. You should give to LaTeX more possibility for image placement, for example with `[ht]˙("hear" or "top"). See comment of Fran!